# Reportar una pequeña falla en la escritura de un mensaje

Tags: bug, soporte, estado-completado

Cuando un usuario con reputación por debajo de 15 ptos intenta votar a favor o en contra en una pregunta o respuesta, el sistema SO le devuelve al usuario el siguiente mensaje:
[image: Mensaje de voto]
Como se muestra en esta imagen hay dos palabras unidas. La palabra "registrados" está unida a la palabra "pero"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Muchas gracias por reportar esto! Se ha corregido el problema. :)

Comment: Ustedes sí que son rápidos. Por eso son la mejor comunidad de preguntas/respuesta sobre desarrollo del mundo. ;)